# Какой смысл констант?

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, masm

Какой смысл констант в ассемблере (masm32)?

Comment: Ну, использование их как константы, наверное?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов их же можно там изменять, а по идее такого не должно быть

Comment: Как и во всех других языках,что бы конкретное значение можно было один раз где то указать и далее в коде не помнить постоянно какое конкретно надо указывать, имена легче запоминать. И в случае если надо будет потом значение изменить, что бы изменить его только в одном месте, а не лазить по всему коду и не менять в 10 местах

Comment: @TyaamovakBrendon, в ассемблере программист имеет право делать всё, хоть даже менять константы.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, ответьте кто нибудь чтобы я проголосовал

Comment: @TyaamovakBrendon все зависит от линкера. Помещение данных в секцию с RO не позволит менять значение.

Comment: Никакой, их можно изменять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Какой смысл констант в ассемблере (masm32)?

Точно такой же, как и в других языках программирования.